# See the ports of all spring boot projects at intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ

Before in Eclipse, with the spring boot plugins or the IDE STS, when lifting the projects I could know which port is using each project.

At this time I'm changing to IntelliJ and I have raised 2 projects at the beginning, I know that 1 goes for port 8080 and the other 8082.

However I currently have 4 projects. In the case that I do not know which project uses which port, is there any way to quickly see this information?

I have attached an image of what the 2 projects look like but I can't see which ports are currently using which one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFpxR.jpg

Comment: The port appears in the console when you start the app.

Comment: correct, I can see it in the console but let's say I lift the 4 projects and make queries to my services is lost port is being used and I can not see it.

my question is if there is a way to see whenever port is using

Comment: I can see it via my endpoints tab (Appears next to Console) and then under the beans tab. What kind of spring boot project are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple modules and therefor run configurations then you should make use of the **Run Dashboard** where you will see what ports your apps are running on. IntelliJ usually suggests to open this when it detects multiple run configurations. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) is some good information on how to set these up.

---

It will look like this (you can see the port like you wanted).

[image: Run Dashboard DEMO]

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has [Spring Boot Dashboard](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/09/intellij-idea-2018-2-auto-detection-spring-boot-run-dashboard/) which when configured will display the port. Do note that the steps to enable it changed in IntelliJ 2018.2, if you have an older version you might have to follow a different tutorial.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If the port number doesn't show up after the application started, you can refresh Endpoints on the Run Dashboard panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Help -> Find Action (ctrl + shift + a) -> Run Dashboard -> Click add service -> select spring boot

[image]

Reference: https://github.com/logbasex/coding-notes/tree/main/ide/intellij